# Could not Cast or Convert System.String to Class object

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string received from a Web API

```
try
{
    string r = await App.client.GetUser();

    App.Authentication = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResult>(r);

    await DisplayAlert("TEST", App.Authentication.ToString(), "OK");

    Application.Current.MainPage = new Schedule();
}
catch (Exception p)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Getting Authentication failed", p.ToString(), "TEST");
}
```

However it gives the error: Could not Cast or Convert System.String to App1.ApiResult
`App.Authentication = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResult>(r);`

App.Authentication:

```
public static ApiResult Authentication = new ApiResult();`
```

JSON string:

> "\"{\\"status\\":\\"0\\",\\"message\\":{\\"ID\\":5,\\"FirstName\\":\\"John\\",\\"LastName\\":\\"Doe\\",\\"Email\\":\\"testemail@gmail.com\\",\\"Password\\":\\"testPass\\",\\"CreationDate\\":\\"2016-10-26T15:01:08\\",\\"RoleID\\":1,\\"doorCode\\":9999}}\""

ApiResult Class:

```
public class ApiResult
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Account message { get; set; }
}
```

Account Class:

```
public class Account
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public int doorCode { get; set; }
}
```

The full error message:

> {"Error converting value
>   \"{\"status\":\"0\",\"message\":{\"ID\":5,\"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"Doe\",\"Email\":\"testemail@gmail.com\",\"Password\":\"testPass\",\"CreationDate\":\"2016-10-26T15:01:08\",\"RoleID\":1,\"doorCode\":9999}}\"
>   to type 'App1.ApiResult'. Path '', line 1, position 232."}

Comment: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

 string r = await App.client.GetUser();

you can check "r" value here.

Comment: Looks like it cant parse date from your message, try to parse it without `CreationDate`.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It appears that the json you receive has been serialized twice - first from `ApiResult` to `string`, then to `string` again:

```
"\"{\\"status\\":\\"0\\",\\"message\\":...
```

The first double-quote might be added by your debugger, but the second (the escaped `\"` one) really appears to be part of the data you're processing. The error message also makes sense this way, it deserializes a `string` and then attempts to cast it to an `ApiResult`.

Try deserializing the data as a string and *then* deserializing its result to an `ApiResult`, to be sure this is the case - and if so, the server code will need to be changed.

Comment: Turns out it was serialized twice. I didn't make the API so I wasn't aware of that. Thank you.

Comment: In my case, my ASP.NET Core server was returning ````Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo))````. Changing it to ````Ok(foo)```` fixed the double-serialization issue.

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResult>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(apiResponse))`.  First deserialize into string and then deserialize as `ApiResult` model class.

Comment: The best answers are the simplest ones. Love you! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 26):

Below code worked for me along the lines of to C.Evenhuis answer,

```
   var content = response.Content;              
   var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content).ToString();
   var result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(jsonResult);
```

Here Content is similar to - 
    "\"{\\"Id\\":\\"92209\\",\\"operatorId\\":100000,\\"Status\\":true, .....

Comment: On jsonResult.. I am getting Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content error...

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. my request was serialized twice, to deseriliaze it, i had to cast it to string using toString() before i called Jsonconvert.Deseriliaze for the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using App.Authentication = JObject.Parse(request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);