# Deserializing a json string into structure results in exception

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I'm having issues mapping a json string returned from sql.

The structure of the object looks like this

```
  public class OrderSummaryDto
  {
        public List<PrescriptionInfo> PrescriptionsInfo { get; set; }

        public class PrescriptionInfo
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public AdministrationInfo Administration { get; set; }

            public class AdministrationInfo
            {
                public string Instructions { get; set; }
                public string PackageType { get; set; }
            }
        }
   }
```

The json string returned from DB

```
[{"Name":"testName","Units":3,"Medium":"flower power","Administration":"{\"Instructions\":\"drIVnkLEm0b24OK9ceMeeF2fq\",\"PackageType\":\"case\"}"},{"Name":"testName","Units":3,"Medium":"flower power","Administration":"{\"Instructions\":\"drIVnkLEm0b24OK9ceMeeF2fq\",\"PackageType\":\"case\"}"}]
```

The Sql that generates the json string

```
(SELECT _co.[Name]  
       ,_co.[Pharmacy_Instructions] AS [Administration]
   FROM [dbo].[Compounds] _co
  WHERE _co.[Id] = 1
    FOR JSON PATH) AS [PrescriptionsInfo]
```

Pharmacy_Instructions is already a JSON formated string

> Message "Could not cast or convert from System.String to
>     Models.Order.Summary.OrderSummaryDto+PrescriptionInfo+AdministrationInfo."  string

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804648/c-sharp-could-not-cast-or-convert-system-string-to-class-object

Comment: `Administration` appears to have been double serialized as evident by `"{\"Instructions\"....`

Comment: your json string seems to be an array of `PrescriptionsInfo` not a `OrderSummaryDto`

Comment: Out of curiosity: why not use a (micro) ORM such as Dapper make your quries return strongly typed objects? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON string is currently a list of PrescriptionInfo Objects, not a OrderSummary object that contains a list of PrescriptionInfo objects. In addition, some fields (Administration) are being treated as strings, instead of objects. The JSON needs to look like this to work properly:

```
{"PrescriptionsInfo": [{"Name":"testName","Units":3,"Medium":"flower power","Administration":{"Instructions":"drIVnkLEm0b24OK9ceMeeF2fq","PackageType":"case"}},{"Name":"testName","Units":3,"Medium":"flower power","Administration":{"Instructions":"drIVnkLEm0b24OK9ceMeeF2fq","PackageType":"case"}}]}
```

Or formatted:

```
{  
   "PrescriptionsInfo":[  
      {  
         "Name":"testName",
         "Units":3,
         "Medium":"flower power",
         "Administration":{  
            "Instructions":"drIVnkLEm0b24OK9ceMeeF2fq",
            "PackageType":"case"
         }
      },
      {  
         "Name":"testName",
         "Units":3,
         "Medium":"flower power",
         "Administration":{  
            "Instructions":"drIVnkLEm0b24OK9ceMeeF2fq",
            "PackageType":"case"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

In order to do this you will have to use aliases. Check out this MS guide
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-nested-json-output-with-path-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

I am weak with JSON support in SQL, might ask with those tags, but it seems like it would be something similar to this.

```
(SELECT _co.[Name],  
       JSON_VALUE(_co.[Pharmacy_Instructions], '$.Instructions') AS "Administration.Instructions",
       JSON_VALUE(_co.[Pharmacy_Instructions], '$.PackageType') AS "Administration.PackageType"
   FROM [dbo].[Compounds] _co
  WHERE _co.[Id] = 1
    FOR JSON PATH) AS [PrescriptionsInfo]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm already investigating the documentation

Comment: I don't have a SQL 2016 server to test this on, but I added what theoretically is what you are needing. You will need to open up the stored JSON string, and then take out the pieces and alias them as the subcomponents that they are. My syntax may be slightly off, as I can't test. I did try to, but my server doesn't support JSON.