# How to convert json value to lowercase - Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, json.net

Please need some help.

I am trying to convert all json value **(not the key)** to lowercase.
I browsed and found only how to convert property name (key), not property value.

I spent the whole day trying to figure out how to do it.

To have somthing like

```
"name": "luke skywalker", 
"hair_color": "blond", 
"skin_color": "fair",
```

Below is the code I'm trying so far. It doesn't work.

```
private static void ChangePropertiesToLowerCase(JObject jsonObject)
        {
            foreach (var property in jsonObject.Properties().ToList())
            {
                if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)// replace property names in child object
                    ChangePropertiesToLowerCase((JObject)property.Value);

                property.Replace(new JProperty(property.Name.ToLower(), property.Value));// properties are read-only, so we have to replace them
            }
        }
```

Below is the json file

```
{
    "count": 82, 
    "next": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2", 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Luke Skywalker", 
            "height": "172", 
            "mass": "77", 
            "hair_color": "blond", 
            "skin_color": "fair", 
            "eye_color": "blue", 
            "birth_year": "19BBY", 
            "gender": "male", 
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/", 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ], 
            "species": [], 
            "vehicles": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/14/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/"
            ], 
            "starships": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/12/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/22/"
            ], 
            "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "C-3PO", 
            "height": "167", 
            "mass": "75", 
            "hair_color": "n/a", 
            "skin_color": "gold", 
            "eye_color": "yellow", 
            "birth_year": "112BBY", 
            "gender": "n/a", 
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/", 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/4/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ], 
            "species": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/species/2/"
            ], 
            "vehicles": [], 
            "starships": [], 
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:10:51.357000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.309000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/"
        }, 
        
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: serialize the json object to string and use string.ToLower() then deserialize back to json object.

Comment: `property.Name.ToLower()` this will lowercase the property name only.. you code is not lowercasing the property value at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) to solve your problem.

You can create your own JsonConverter to handle string value. In the following code I created this customer JsonConverter to convert string values to lower case while writing to JSON.

```
public class StringConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // converting to lower case string while writing to JSON outcome.
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToLower());
    }

    public override string ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, string existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // returning the value without change while deserializing.
        return (string)reader.Value;
    }
}
```

And following is the way you can use the above converter.

```
// let say your class name is SearchResult;
// JSON string is stored in jsonString variable.


var searchResult = JsonConvert.Deserialize<SearchResult>(jsonString);

var jsonStringLowerCase = JsonConvert.Serialize(jsonString, new StringConverter());
```

With above code `jsonStringLowerCase` will have JSON with all the string property values converted to lower case.

I hope this will help you solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's helped. but I got an error saying : *Could not cast or convert from System.String to **mycustomObjectType.*** So I was supposed to deserialize it as string first, then deserialize again to **mycustomObjectType.**  See reference [here]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804648/could-not-cast-or-convert-system-string-to-class-object.

Comment: How Can I contact you in private, Please I have couple of questions to ask regarding how to become a Senior dev or Principal dev like you. Trying to access http://www.dotawsnet.com/ but it's down.

Comment: I'm trying to move your above StringConverter class into a helper class but the override methods cannot be turned static. Can you please assist ? I need to move it to a helper class so I can use it anywhere.

Comment: `StringConverter` is a class inherited from `JsonConverter` class. `JsonConverter` class is from Newsoft.Json library. So you can't use it as helper or static. You need to create an object of that class and pass it to Serialize method as I have done it in ` JsonConvert.Serialize(jsonString, new StringConverter());`

Comment: My solution first Deserialize the JSON string to C# class object (I assume that you have a JSON string as input). Then I serialize that object back to JSON but this time using converter so that string properties are serialized in lower case values.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's helped me. I just want to ask you a small question. I want to become a senior dev, and just want to know. How did you discover the **StringConverter** class?  did you use it before??  or after you saw my post here in so you just browsed json newton web site to find the answer ?   I'm asking cause I need to start reading library documentation as well rather than posting code on forum.  I just want to know the path you followed to give me that StringConverter class !!!

Comment: @User456 I have been using Newtonsoft.Json since long time. With the usage I learned that it offers lot of customization and not just simple JSON serialization. After reading your question I checked the [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyItemLevelSetting.htm) documentation and while going thru that I noticed [CustomJsonConverter<T>](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) on the same page. I read more and write some experiment code to try solve  your problem and then shared the working solution here.

Comment: Thank you so so much for describing it. I did not know that you wrote code on your side to help me. Respect for that !!! Again thank you so much.